# Unable to use moveRowAtIndexPath for tableView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, tableview

Currently I display a simple array of objects in my custom tableview, I have also used [SwipyCell](https://github.com/moritzsternemann/SwipyCell) to test swipe gestures.

I am then trying to reorder the objects using `moveRowAtIndexPath` however for some reason it does not work with the following code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let itemThatMoved = self.tasks[sourceIndexPath.row]
    self.array.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    self.array.insert(itemThatMoved, at: destinationIndexPath.row)


     // Change data properties

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return true
}
```

I have also set the following in my ViewController

```
table.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
table.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = true
table.allowsSelection = true
```

Does anyone have any suggestions what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Is this really supposed to be Swift 2? If *yes* you are encouraged to update. If *no* the signatures of the delegate methods are wrong.

Comment: @vadian could you elaborate ? No it is not supposed to be Swift 2

Comment: How did you add these two delegate methods? Did you copy and paste from some example code? Don't copy old code and don't type them yourself. Let Xcode enter most of it for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Swift 3+ the signatures of the delegate methods are wrong

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool
```

and

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath)
```

Comment: Then your code is messed up in another way. It seems that you've copied&pasted Swift 2 code in a Swift 3+ environment.